# Is there an alternative to LiveStream?

Tags: web-development, streaming

I´m looking for an alternative to LiveStream, I mean, a free live streaming solution for video broadcasting and then embedding the player in my website.

- Bandwidth limitations is OK.
- Concurrent users limitation is OK.
- 24/7 transmission capabilities.

[**Note**: no 'stream' or 'streaming' tag available, please re-tag]

Comment: Added "streaming" tag per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some good choices would be:

- UStream
- Justin.tv

That said, I have never used either of these, but I've heard really good things about UStream and I can confirm that you can embed the players on your site.

Comment: What about streaming speed ? Since we are relying on a web service will we not have issues concerning the streaming speed ?